# CORS Filter in Scala Play 2.2 application

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, cors

I want to implement a CORS filter in my Play 2.2.x application. So far I have the following:

```
package filters

import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
import play.api.GlobalSettings

class CorsFilter extends EssentialFilter {
  def apply(next: EssentialAction) = new EssentialAction {
    def apply(requestHeader: RequestHeader) = {
      next(requestHeader).map { result =>
        result.withHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Origin" -> "*",
          "Access-Control-Expose-Headers" -> "WWW-Authenticate, Server-Authorization",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" -> "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" -> "x-requested-with,content-type,Cache-Control,Pragma,Date")
      }
    }
  }
}

object Global extends WithFilters(new CorsFilter) with GlobalSettings
```

as well as a preflight options action:

```
  def preflight(all: String) = Action {
    Ok("").withHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Origin" -> "*",
      "Allow" -> "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" -> "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" -> "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Referrer, User-Agent");
  }
```

with a route defined:

```
OPTIONS        /*all                                controllers.Application.preflight(all: String)
```

What seems to be happening is that CorsFilter code isn't being executed. I have my debugger open and I don't see any of my requests hitting this filter. Why would this be? Is there somewhere else I need to define the filter stuff so that Play can see it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GlobalSettings` object needs to be in the default package, so `package filters` is causing it to be ignored by Play. I'd suggest moving it to it's own file `Global.scala`.

Comment: Wow, that works. I spent so much time trying to figure out what the issue was, this would have been the last place I'd have thought. Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: Also see http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/SecurityHeaders although note https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2967#issuecomment-45949778

Answer (score 3):

For a similar project, trying to get an AngularJS web client communicating with a Scala server, the  headers you used didn't work.  We used:

```
    ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN -> "*",
    ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS -> "GET, POST, OPTIONS",
    ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS ->  "Origin, Accept, Authorization, X-Auth-Token",
    ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS -> "true"
```

We had the Global object in its own file as LimbSoup suggested.  We borrowed the mainstay of the code from https://gist.github.com/jeantil/7214962 but hard-coded the headers instead of implementing them programmatically.